# React Native flatlist with checkbox

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I am writing the code in class component, I need a flatlist with checkbox that allow multiple select, add the selected data could be save in a array and pass to other screen. I have no idea about that.. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
import React, {  Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Body } from 'native-base';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            serachdata: [],
            selectedId: []
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.ApiCalling();
    }

    ApiCalling = () => {
        const url = "YOUR_API"
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({data: res.data})
                this.setState({serachdata: res.data})
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error ", error)
            })
    }

    onCheckBoxPress = (id) => {
        let checkboxes = this.state.selectedId;
        if(checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(id)){
            checkboxes.splice( checkboxes.indexOf(id), 1 );
        } else {
            checkboxes = checkboxes.concat(id);
        }
        this.setState({selectedId:checkboxes})
        console.log("selectde checkbox id: ", checkboxes)
      }

       _filter = (text) => {
        const newData = this.state.data.filter(item => {   
          const itemData = `${item.first_name.toUpperCase()}`; 
          const textData = text.toUpperCase();
          return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });
        this.setState({serachdata:newData})
      }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
            <TextInput
                autoCapitalize='none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, margin:10 }}
                status='info'
                placeholder='Search'
                onChangeText={(text) => this._filter(text)}
                textStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
            />
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.serachdata}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                    return(
                    <ListItem key={index}>
                            <CheckBox
                                disabled={false}
                                value={this.state.selectedId && this.state.selectedId.includes(item.id)}
                                onChange={()=>this.onCheckBoxPress(item.id)}
                            />
                        <Body>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                                <Image source={{ uri: item.avatar }} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
                                <Text>{item.first_name}</Text>
                                <Text>{item.email}</Text>
                                {/* <Text>{item.name.last}</Text> */}
                            </View>
                        </Body>
                    </ListItem>)}}
            />
        </View>
        )
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks, it work!! How if I need a search function to filter the item by the name entered??